# Drawing text on a gif while preserving transparency [FFMPEG]

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

Using the regular method, input > drawtext seems to remove transparency for GIFs and messes with the coloring

```
ffmpeg -i test.gif drawtext=text='Test':fontcolor=red:fontsize=24 output.gif
```

I've always tried using filter complex's palettegen and paletteuse, but those require arguments that drawtext doesn't provide:

```
ffmpeg -i banner.gif -filter_complex "[0:v] drawtext=text='Test':fontcolor=red:fontsize=24 [a]; [a] palettegen=reserve_transparent=1 [b]; paletteuse [a][b]" output.gif
```

What's the best way to efficiently draw text while preserving transparency?

Comment: According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality) post, the syntax is: `ffmpeg -y -i test.gif -filter_complex "drawtext=text='Test':fontcolor=red:fontsize=24,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=reserve_transparent=1[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif`. I tested it, and it's working. The red color becomes part of the new palette, and some of the original pixels turns red (particularly around transparent areas).

Comment: I've searched this site for hours for a solution and somehow missed that post, thank you so much! @Rotem

Comment: In case you want me to post it as an answer, please post the question in Super User site, and delete it from here (since this is not a programming question, I don't want to post an answer in Stack Overflow).

Comment: Sure thing, here you go: https://superuser.com/questions/1703971/drawing-text-on-a-gif-while-preserving-transparency-ffmpeg